# No Output in Console Java

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, primes

I am creating a program in which it generates prime numbers up to a certain number entered by the user. When I type in the number when running the program the program doesn't output anything, and is still running and I can't figure out why. I've tried using a double instead of an int and I've tried using i++ instead of ++i neither fixed the problem. Someone Please help!! This is the code i wrote:

```
package assignment_4_1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment_4_1 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number above 50 to find all of the primes between 1 and that number: ");
    int upto = input.nextInt();
    int firstloop = 1;
        while(firstloop < upto)
        {
            for(int i=2; i<=firstloop; ++i)
            {
               double secondloop;
               if(firstloop % i == 0)
               {
                   secondloop = 0;
               }
               secondloop = 1;
               if(secondloop == 1);
               {
                   System.out.println(firstloop);
               }
               firstloop++;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Thanks to who ever can tell me what I 'm doing wrong.

Comment: You also have an if statement that does nothing with `if(secondloop == 1);`, the next block would conditionally execute instead of always execute if you removed the semi colon.

Comment: @mdl that was my problem thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wanna debug your code , try it with small values, pencil nd paper , you can test your loops tests all of it , to get the prime values or numbers , we actually should start by the definition of prime number : number not devided only but by 1 and it self , , if number is not prime , so their is n as 1 < n< number and number/n=real === number%n=0 and more precisely is 1< n/number<2 so :

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); 
int number= input.nextInt();
boolean prime;
for (int i=1;i<=number;i++)
{
prime=true;
for(int j=2;j<=i/2;j++)
{
if(i%j==0)
{
prime=false;
break;
}
}
if(prime)
{
System.out.println(i+",");
}
}
```

Comment: i was using % as in saying if it is left with no remainder than its not prime

Comment: the ; after if will prevent from entering the test so there is no output !

Comment: beside that the if has no meaning   secondloop = 1;
            if(secondloop == 1);
            {
                System.out.println(firstloop);
            }

Answer (score 0):

It never goes in this loop, because first loop is 1,i is 2. 
And so i is never <= firstloop:

```
for(int i=2; i<=firstloop; ++i) {
```

So firstloop never gets incremented and it loops forever.

Comment: Actually that firstloop++ is inside the for (which never gets entered) Its quite hard to read due to poor indentation. So first loop never gets incremented and the value of upto is irrelevant

Comment: I think theres a moral to this story for the O.P

Answer (score 0):

if you would correctly indent your code you may see, that you increase `firstloop` **inside** the for loop! The for-loop on the other hand will never execute, since in `for(int i=2; i<=firstloop; ++i)` `i` is always greater than `firstloop`

Comment: what do you mean by correctly indenting my code im taking a programming class online and it has never said anything about proper indentation. How do I achieve "Proper Indentation"

Comment: correct indentation helps you (and us) to understand your code more quickly and find the mistakes you actually made. For starters : each closing-bracket should be on the same height as the corresponding opening-bracket and each content between those should be more indented  (e.g. 4 spaces more) http://mbreen.com/javastyle.html